# Removing formatting when reading from file

Tags: python

I'm creating an online bank program. The users recent transactions are stored in a logs file. The user has the ability to display their log file to see recent transactions. I have managed to get the program to print the file but I need to remove the formatting and separate each log onto separate lines

## What the user currently gets printed

```
['01-01-2020 22:02: Moved £564 from balance to savings\n', '02-01-2020 01:11: Moved £345 from savings to balance\n']
```

## What I need to be printed

```
01-01-2020 22:02: Moved £564 from balance to savings
02-01-2020 01:11: Moved £345 from savings to balance
```

## Code for reading the file

```
def log_show(id):
    with open(id + " log.txt", 'r') as log:
        logs = log.readlines()
        print(logs)
        log.close()
```

## Example for writing a transaction to the file

```
    
with open(data["ID"] + " log.txt", "a") as log:
       log.write(now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M") + ": Moved £"+ str(amount) + " from balance to savings\n")
```

The only way I've though I could do it is by reading each line separately then slicing the formatted parts of the end, but unsure how I can do this

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: You're printing the list with `print(logs)`, instead of the elements in the list. `readlines()` reads all of the lines, while you want to read one line at a time and print it.

Comment: `for line in logs: print(line.strip())`